# Matlab imtranslate function for bitmap (bmp) images

Tags: image, matlab, bitmap, transform, bmp

I have been trying to do an imtranslate on a .bmp file but I only get an error that says '??? Undefined function or method 'imtranslate' for input arguments of type 'uint8'. I do have the image processing toolbox and matlab R2011a.  Here is my code:

```
D=dir('*.bmp');    
imcell=cell(1,numel(D));    
for i=1:numel(D)    
imcell{i}=imread(D(i).name,'bmp');   
end   

imtrans=imtranslate(imcell{1},[25,25]);
```

Comment: Can you improve your question putting a little bit more information? What is the error you get, paste it here. How are you inputting your command? Give a minimal example so that we can reproduce it and check if we can help you x)

Comment: Are you passing the image file or the image matrix to `imtransform`? Please note that that function takes in the matrix. If you could at least post the error message ...

Comment: `imtransform` works with image data read in through `imread`.  It is independent of the kind of image you provide.  The whole purpose of `imread` is to **decode** the compressed image data from the relevant standards (TIF, JPEG, BMP, etc.) so that you can work with it.  You shouldn't have to convert between image standards.  Also, please provide **all code** you have written and the exact error that MATLAB gives you.  We can't help you diagnose or solve your problem with so little information given.

Comment: @Werner So all I have been doing is uploading an image sequence and trying to translate them all proportionally using a for loop.  At first, though I just want to see if imtranslate works for one image and I get the error.
To upload the image sequence I have this code:

D=dir('*.bmp');
imcell=cell(1,numel(D));
for i=numel(D)
imcell{i}=imread(D(i).name,'bmp');
end

Comment: @LordHenryWotton then I try to view the image by this:

Comment: @LordHenryWotton then I try to view just the first image translated 25x25 pixels by this:
imtrans=imtranslate(imcell{1},[25,25]);
and I then get the error:
??? Undefined function or method 'imtranslate' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

Error in ==> VideoTranslation at 17
imtrans=imtranslate(imcell{1},[25,25]);

So I'm not really sure why imtranslate is undefined

Comment: @rayryeng I can view image(imcell{1}) easily so I know there isn't an issue with that.  It wont let me tag you all in the comments so hopefully you all see  this from my three comment tags!  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @AlexBulkyBulk - What happens when you do `imshow(imcell{1});`?  If you also get an undefined error, that means you don't have the image processing toolbox installed.  As such, none of the image processing methods that you are using will work.

Comment: @AlexBulkyBulk - Please post **all of your code** for God's sake.  I don't want to have to diagnose your problem completely with comments.  Please update your question.

Comment: @AlexBulkyBulk - Actually, please read this article before updating your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @rayryeng sorry first time using this site.  I checked and I do in fact have image processing toolbox, but when I type in imshow(imcell{1}); it gives me a blank image.  And I provided my entire code starting in the comment to Werner.  It's not very big and I couldn't see from the article you gave if there was an easier way to post comments of code so that each line would separate.  I'll post the entire code one more time.  By the way, I have checked the computer I'm using and I have matlab R2011a. I've tried to see if there was different syntax back then but can't find anything

Comment: @AlexBulkyBulk Do **not** put your code in comments. Edit your original question and add the code there with proper code formatting.

Comment: @beaker I'm sorry I'm frustrating everyone.  I can't seem to find any information on this site as to what is proper code formatting

Comment: @AlexBulkyBulk In your original question, below the [image], [matlab] tags, there's an option called `edit`. Click this and it will allow you to modify your original question. When you want to insert code, put `4 spaces` before each line of code and the editor will separate your code from the rest of the text.

Comment: Please, add the error you are getting after input your command x)

Comment: All, I have figured out the answer.  In R2011, there is only a function to transform a structured element and use that to dilate the image using imdilate.  Thanks for the help!